# vector sum/subtraction magnitude

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I got stuck in a multiple choice assignment.

The angle between $u,v$ is $120$ degrees, with $||u||$ = 4, $||v||$ = 3.

I need to calculate $||(u - v)||$ and $||(u + v)||$. I used $(||u||^ 2 + ||v||^ 2-2 ||u|| \ ||v|| \cos(x))^ 2$ but still not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u \cdot v = \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert \cos \theta$

$u \cdot v = 12 \cos 120^0 = -6$

$\lVert u + v \rVert^2=(u+v)\cdot(u+v)=\lVert u\rVert^2+\lVert v\rVert^2+2(u\cdot v) = 3^2 + 4^2 + 2 \times (-6) = 13$

So, $\lVert u + v \rVert = \sqrt {13}$

$\lVert u - v \rVert^2=(u-v)\cdot(u-v)=\lVert u\rVert^2+\lVert v\rVert^2 - 2(u\cdot v) = 3^2 + 4^2 - 2 \times (-6) = 37$

So, $\lVert u - v \rVert = \sqrt {37}$

Comment: the angle between them is 120 degrees. shouldn't their sum be large? because the big angle sees the edge.

Comment: No if you draw the parallelogram, you can see that is really $u-v$.

Comment: okey thanks buddy, ı got it!

Comment: You are welcome. I was adding a diagram. If you are clear, I will leave it otherwise I will add it.

Comment: thanks man!, ı'm clear. no needed :)